# Jquery - ReadLess toggle function

Tags: jquery

I have old jquery code (from version 1.7.1) and want it to start workin on version 3.x

Tried to change it and I failed a bit :<

Here is example of code: http://jsfiddle.net/lilpri/S3Rfu/106/

```
$(function(){
$('.opis').each(function(){
    $(this).append('<div class="readmore">czytaj więcej...</div>');
    var textelement = $(this).find('.text');
    var wys = textelement.height();
    textelement.css('height', '80px');
    $(this).find('.readmore').on('click', function(){
        textelement.animate({height: wys}, 1000);
        $(this).attr('class', 'readless');
        $(this).text('czytaj mniej...');
    });
    $(this).find('.readless').on('click', function(){
        textelement.animate({height: '80px'}, 1000);
        $(this).attr('class', 'readmore');
        $(this).text('czytaj więcej...');
    });
}); });
```

And here is the old code with .live() function: http://jsfiddle.net/lilpri/S3Rfu/105/

```
$(function(){
$('.opis').each(function(){
    $(this).append('<div class="readmore">czytaj więcej...</div>');
    var textelement = $(this).find('.text');
    var wys = textelement.height();
    textelement.css('height', '80px');
    $(this).find('.readmore').live('click', function(){
        textelement.animate({height: wys}, 1000);
        $(this).attr('class', 'readless');
        $(this).text('czytaj mniej...');
    });
    $(this).find('.readless').live('click', function(){
        textelement.animate({height: '200px'}, 1000);
        $(this).attr('class', 'readmore');
        $(this).text('czytaj więcej...');
    });
});});
```

As you can see in this code is a example of dynamic generate a div.

It's working fine while you want to show more, its changing name of class of this div and don't know why it couldn't enter a next part (in this example a readless, that can hide part of text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`live()` is different from a standard `on("click", function() {...});` because `live()` preserves the event, meaning elements that are dynamically added will still obey this handler. By simply using `on` as you have in your code, you're trying to attach events to elements that don't yet exist.

Luckily, `on()` allows us to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), which actually attaches the event to the unchanging *parent*, thus preserving the event for dynamically-added elements. Try this instead:

```
//YOUR OLD CODE
$(this).find('.readless').live('click', function(){

//THE NEW CODE
$(this).on('click', '.readless', function(){
```

This will attach a click event to `$(this)`, which only fires if the clicked element matches the second parameter `.readless`.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery documentation shows how best to convert this:

```
$( "a.offsite" ).live( "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); 
});
$( document ).on( "click", "a.offsite", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

---

Your `live` event handler would translate to:

```
$(this).on('click', '.readmore', function(){
```